# When I logged in to the Graphic Design Beta site with my OpenID, why didn't any account data transfer in?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I've been a stack exchange user for quite awhile and every other time I've logged in to a new site, my existing stack exchange account preferences have all populated the account at the new site, and I've gotten a rep bonus as well.

However, when I just signed up for the Graphic Design Beta site, this didn't happen at all. The account was linked with the rest of my accounts, but only my name was populated, and none of the other information was at all. There also isn't any way to copy in the info from my other profiles either.

Is this a bug? Did I do something wrong? Is the MyOpenID provider malfunctioning somehow?

Comment: That happened to me also. I got a little more data in my new profile, but not everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - I think it's the other way round (based on time of post creation), but my issue is more with the account data not getting transferred in whereas the question you duped to is _only_ about the rep (which to me is minor)

Comment: @cdeszaq ah, true, sorry. But still closely related

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - Yes, _very_ closely related. No worries though... I almost marked as a dup myself ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is directly related to [the association not happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep), tomorrow (barring any unforeseen issues) that fix will be deployed and this will be fixed going forward.

As for profiles, you can push your profile from another site to all others either on the edit screen or the accounts tab in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, seeing the same thing on [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/20080/ben-duguid) too.

Signing in resulted in the usual "we have 17 other accounts for you shall we link them up" message, but I've got a default gravatar (no email address has come through) and no profile information has been pulled in, however my 17 other accounts are listed.

Like cdeszaq I'm not that fussed about the additional rep at this stage, but having to force my profile through seems a bit excessive.

Comment: I _did_ discover that if you go into one of your other filled-in profiles and click "apply to all linked accounts" (or something like that), it _will_ propagate and fill in the new account correctly.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was still working but it used to do this automatically ;)