# Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, linked-accounts

I just created an account at [outdoors.SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com) (via MyOpenID) to answer a question migrated there, and noticed that I had **1** rep, despite having over 200 rep on several other StackExchange network sites, which [should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) let me start from 101 rep.

My [user profile](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/382/ilmari-karonen) does list several linked accounts (including my SO account with 5k+ rep), so that's apparently not the problem.  However, I did notice that the e-mail and website fields in my profile were not automatically filled, so I had to add my e-mail manually to get my usual gravatar.

Just to confirm that it wasn't an isolated problem, I went and created an account at [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com), where I also didn't have one before (this time via StackExchange OpenID, since MyOpenID wasn't working), and experienced the same issue.  So it appears that this bug is reproducible.

**Addendum:** While writing this post, I went back and reloaded my profile page on outdoors.SE, and it appears that I now have 101 rep there (and a message bar congratulating me for gaining "create chat rooms and 9 other privileges").  However, cstheory.SE still shows me at 1 rep.

**Edit:** I just noticed that the new reputation page now shows the "Association Bonus", so I checked it out.  Apparently, I created my outdoors.se account at `2012-03-12 21:07:59Z`, but only gained the association bonus **one hour and 47 minutes later**, at `2012-03-12 22:54:33Z`.  On cstheory.SE, my reputation events list is still empty.

**Why isn't the association bonus applied immediately upon account creation?**  I'm pretty sure it used to work that way, and the current behavior seems like a significant user interface regression.  If I create an account on a new site, it's because I want to *do* something on that site that I can't do just as well without logging in — not because I want to wait two hours and then come back to do whatever it was I meant to do.

**Edit 2:** It's now been over 12 hours since I created an account on cstheory.SE, and I *still* have only 1 rep there.  Apparently, something more than just waiting is now needed to trigger the bonus.

**Edit 3:** My 100 rep bonus on cstheory.SE was finally awarded just one minute before Nick Craver posted his answer below.  However, [my stats.SE account](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/9808/ilmari-karonen), created 20 minutes ago, is still at 1 rep.

**Edit 4:** Just created an account on [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and got the association bonus immediately.  Looks like [this has indeed been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125477).  Thanks, Nick!

Comment: It takes a while to update, apparently. Was it minutes or hours? Maybe you need to do something to make it update, I seem to remember some things were only updated upon user activity.

Comment: @Daniel: It was just shy of two hours, apparently, which is IMO a bit excessive, especially if one creates an account specifically to do something that needs more than 1 rep (like, say, posting an answer with more than two links). Surely it shouldn't be that hard to apply the bonus immediately?

Comment: I can confirm this problem. It happened when I registered at a site, http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/3639. It seems something regarding the 100 rep bonus broke today. Previously the bonus was awarded immediately.

Comment: [me too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125470/146482)

Comment: I had the same issue, as well as issues transferring in account info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125417

Comment: Same here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125482/merged-account-has-no-linked-user-info

Comment: Although I don't doubt the validity of your statements, I am curious about why you __need__ that +100 bonus to show up in 20 minutes or less.

Comment: @PopularDemand - In my case, I ended up at a question that had issues that I wanted to help fix (suggested edit, flag, comment, etc.), but with only 1 rep, there isn't really much that can be done. Waiting for the rep to get bumped with the association bonus defeats the purpose in this case, since I just wanted to offer a quick fix and move on, rather than having to come back.

Comment: @PopularDemand: drive by voting or commenting? You'd found an answer that addressed your pressing need and wanted to reward the people involved and would forget to come back in an hour?

Comment: Bleh. If you cared that much, you wouldn't forget. Or at the very least you'd write yourself a reminder. And generally, a single edit/vote/flag doesn't seem very significant to me. There are other users. Now, in the interest of fairness, I will point out that I can't run a cost-benefit on improving the performance of bonus awarding since I don't know the cost. I just feel like even a minimal cost would outweigh the benefit.

Comment: @PopularDemand: This discussion is probably all beside the point, since Nick has confirmed that the delay is a bug and will be fixed. But every time I see something that I want to vote or comment on, on a site that I don't yet have an account on, I think "Is making this contribution worth the trouble of creating a new account?" Sometimes the answer is "yes", sometimes "no". If the process also involved a delay of even five minutes (much less 20 minutes or even hours), that answer would almost always be "no". [Which might be a shame.](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5837#comment7174_5838)

Comment: @PopularDemand also, it used to be immediate - I could sign-up to a site and vote immediately, not have to wait even twenty minutes. As Ivan notes in the comments to Nick's answer, he's been waiting a day ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I know, I was the one who pointed Ivan here; he asked a question like this about half an hour ago and I voted to close as a dupe of this. The "used to be immediate" is news to me, though.

Comment: Yep, registered on Judaism purely to respond to a comment thread on 28/2 and didn't have to wait - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1291/zhaph-ben-duguid?tab=activity

Comment: @popular: Or [your question gets migrated and you'd like to participate on the target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125588/migration-to-a-site-where-i-have-no-account-is-a-very-bad-user-experience).

Comment: It happened to me too, when I logged in to the "German Language & Usage" site. My other sites where all listed, but the reputation is just 1.

Comment: Ooh. Now __that__ is a good use case, @sarnold. Perhaps I could get behind this after all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an ongoing issue, and it's been a long time coming - the association code hasn't changed in quite some time.

I'm in the process of totally re-writing how all of this works behind the scenes to be both faster and more reliable.  I hope to get this deployed tomorrow then will run some cleanup and make sure all association bonuses get rewarded (and a few ancient dupes cleaned up as well).

**Update:** This fix is deployed, and I've run a backfill of what should be all missing association bonuses everywhere on the network.

Comment: still the case for [my account](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/4003/user4003) and [another one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3995/) mentioned in [this dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125417/when-i-logged-in-to-the-graphic-design-beta-site-with-my-openid-why-didnt-any)

Comment: Unaccepting for now, seems like there's still some issues left: I did get my 100 rep bonus on cstheory.SE, but I just created an account at stats.SE five minutes ago and it's still at 1 rep. :/

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Yes, my new account on Graphic Design hasn't changed.

Comment: Scratch that, just took a bit to update...silly caches

Comment: Oh this is going to be fun, may need to re-write how this bonus is granted, hang on we're aware of the issue and will see if we can greatly simplify how this is done now.

Comment: I've created an [account on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/16538/ivan-kharlamov) more than a day ago and still didn't get my +100 reputation.

Comment: @IvanKharlamovn - Yes, we're aware - I'm totally rewriting how this works.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Please check that answers are correctly linked too; that failed for me also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125520/why-do-i-only-have-a-reputation-of-1-on-codereview-when-i-have-lots-on-other-sit

Comment: @Nick: While you're hard at work, could you maybe retag this question as [meta-tag:status-reproduced] or something. I'd do it myself, but, you know... (Oh, and many, many thanks for taking your time to look into this issue.)

Comment: @NickCraver: I'm also facing the same issue on FrenchSE, I have reported in http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/308/the-website-does-completely-detec-my-other-se-accounts. Is there anything we can do to help you?

Comment: Confirmed fixed on my [hermeneutics.se] account.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still seeing some odd behavior.  I just joined the [homebrew](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/2424/user2424) site and it didn't link properly.  [Here](http://stackexchange.com/users/1520701/user2424?tab=accounts) it says "user2424" next to my profile pic, but "raven" up at the top.  If I click on "accounts" on this page it just shows the homebrew account, but if I click on "raven", then "accounts" I see all my SE accounts.  Is there still some delay between joining a site and the account association rectification?