# How do I merge split communities

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I used to have only a stack overflow account. Later I used this account to link a number of different communities.

Now, I was joining Area 51 this week and it required me to make a new account, which did not get linked to SO. In an attempt to rectify, I tried login in to the main stackexchange site, using the same OpenID provider (facebook).

But now, any new SE community I join, gets listed in the SE account and my list on SO remains as it was. I am continuous signed in on both sites. Can someone help me out?

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep), but since that bug has long be fixed, I assume my problems are different (and maybe my own error). I tried to user account merge on stackoverflow, but it denies the use address of stack exchange.

[My stackoverflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816774/tim)