# Merged account has no linked user info

Tags: bug, openid, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I logged in to the Graphic Design Beta site with my OpenID, why didn't any account data transfer in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125417/when-i-logged-in-to-the-graphic-design-beta-site-with-my-openid-why-didnt-any)

I have [several accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137232/powtac?tab=accounts) on the stack network. All of them are assigned to my Yahoo OpenID. In the past when I "registered" for a new stack area my new account got all the personal information like the avatar, my age... from the other accounts. But today when I tried to register for the [DIY area](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), my other accounts got recognized but after I clicked on <kbd>Confirm and create new Account</kbd>...

[image: My linked account are shown]

...my [profile page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/5553/simon-bruchner) had only my name showed up but nothing else. :(

[image: My empty new profile]

*I will soon delete this DIY account, but I will leave it for several hours to comprehend this bug.*

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep