# Why do I only have a reputation of 1 on codereview when I have lots on other sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep)

I just created my account on codereview.stackexchange and have a [reputation of 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150077/marc-andre-lafortune?tab=accounts). Clearly my other accounts are linked properly, but no information was copied over from stackoverflow (i.e. bio, dob, etc...)

It looks like [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/refactor-method-in-ruby) that was migrated there is not linked to me, at least it doesn't show in my answers (and I would have a 21 rep).

Login was made using open ID.

Hopefully someone can fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of these two questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125439/33051 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125417/33051

Comment: Albeit the lack of question linking appears to be new

Comment: Have you tried going to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/reputation and triggering a rep recalc?

Comment: @Ladadadada: Tried it, no change.

Comment: I manually ran the association stuff on you there, but will account for this in the backfill.