# Creating account on new SE site - only 1 rep, no profile copy

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, network-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep)

I just created a profile in Academia.SE and two unexpected errors happened:

- my profile was not copied (I ended up as user410 instead of Tomas)
- I got only rep 1 - I should got 101.

Note that the accounts **are** linked - if I go to the [accounts tab at Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/410/user410?tab=accounts), I see the other accounts of mine, with Academia being also on the list.

I've looked at the [list of recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) but as it is missing there I consider this as a bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Just created an account on a new SE site, where's my +100 rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125417/when-i-logged-in-to-the-graphic-design-beta-site-with-my-openid-why-didnt-any

Comment: The first linked question is really a clutter. Why cannot people formulate briefly and go straight to the issue? Maybe the linked question should be marked duplicate of this one. :-)

Comment: The title is for going "straight to the issue". The question body provides further context and explanation.